# Edit Document has been grayed out after migration from SP2010-SP2013

Tags: document-library, migration

Hi we have migrated our environment from 2010 to 2013. In Document libraries when trying to select the pdf files and try to edit the document it shows its been grayed out. I am having full administrative access on the sites and libraries. Please find the attached screenshot . Let me know if any one has solution for this. [image]

Comment: does it work for other types of documents?

Comment: Yes it does work with word docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/12336546-open-adobe-pdf-in-client-application) in SharePoint 2013: PDF-Files cannot be edited directly.

Some workarounds until Microsoft might fix that:

- Manually Download the PDF, Edit it, Save it locally, Upload again.
- Use the "Open in Explorer" Button
- Implement [PDFFIX.JS](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1379554). Also note the discussion about HTTP and HTTPS. Put this on your Update-Checklist, as it might break after installing a Cumulative Update.

Please support the UserVoice-Idea linked above if you also face that problem and want it to get fixed by MS.

Comment: the link you provided is showing in particular to Office 365 only. Is it same thing in on premise  SharePoint 2013/2016 as well?

Comment: This also applies for OnPremises Installations. Follow the pdffix.js link for an very interesting discussion.